# Numerical Computation: Quantum Field Theory and General Relativity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, computational-physics

Since I am only caught up in text book type problems and calculations, I rarely use a computer to help out with a computation.  The one exception is to use Mathematica for mundane things that just help get to the answer (Integration, plotting graphs, and so on).

But, I read that real-world problems are those that require rather large and complex computer based computation to arrive at reasonable answers.  I know of this but know little about the methods and the size of problems that are considered routine by professional particle physicists or those who work in astrophysics or cosmology with real-world models demanding numerical General Relativity.

Question:  Just how large and complex are these computations?  Are they the sort of thing requiring hours and hours of super-computer time?  For example, the size and complexity of analysis of particle interactions in detectors at CERN.  Or, with General Relativity, the types of calculations that would have been involved in the model of two spiraling and colliding black holes that produce the gravitational waves detected by LIGO.

For this question, I understand that precise or specific answers may not be meaningful to me as general examples of actual computations that are carried out.

Comment: Some are VERY LARGE and extremely complex. You can download some of these packages in source code and you can browse trough it, if you like. Numerical math is a discipline of its own, which should probably tell you something. Hours of computing time? Talk about six months on 1,000 or 10,000 CPUs...

Comment: @CuriousOne     I knew that they were large but probably would never have guessed that large.  Before I retired, I spent 40 years as a software developer (and sometimes mathematician and engineer) working with applications used for managing the transmission grid, generation, and wholesale energy markets.  We had big problems, on order of 20 million unknowns but not super long computations.

Comment: Yeah... a lot of this is really brute forcing after whatever simplifications can be made somewhat defensibly have been made (to be honest, many simplifications sound like gross oversimplifications to me!). In the 1980s I was desperate to get my hands on a supercomputer once or twice, today I am writing this on a machine that is hundreds of times faster and I rarely do any numerical stuff on it... what this machine can do is simply of no interest, today, as far as scientific numerical calculations are concerned. The problems are always larger than the machine one has... :-(

Comment: @CuriousOne doesn't go quite far enough. 6 months on 10,000 cores is only 7 million core-hours. There are projects that take 100 million core hours, and the next generation of computers being built will allocate time in billion core-hour chunks.

Comment: Consider just a simple grid method for solving a hyperbolic PDE (one of the most ubiquitous and easiest things to do in scientific computation). If you want 10,000 cells in each dimension and enough timesteps to cover 100 signal-crossing times, with 1000 operations per cell update (very optimistic) that comes out to $10^{21}$ operations, which is 10 million core-hours right there.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I didn't want to sound too greedy, but you are absolutely correct, the computations are growing exponentially and are absolutely insanely large by any standard we had just a few decades ago.

Comment: It strongly depends on what you are doing: Full 4D simulations with no symmetries and a lot of physics can get very expensive. Examples would be neutron stars or black hole mergers with full GR and MHD (ideal or even resistive). It gets simpler if you can reduce dimensions: static problems, axis-symmetric problems. 2D calculations with full GR and ideal MHD of magnetized neutron stars can be done on a personal computer in between 1-5 minutes per star. 1D calculations (TOV-equation, Hartle-Thorne method) of static or rotating stars only run in a few seconds on a personal computer.

Comment: @M.J.Steil      Your comment is more in-line with the kind of answer I was looking for that gives a brief overview of a given application.  The thing is, I could invent some silly computation that will occupy a supercomputer for as long as desired but that is not my interest -- it is examples of the types of problems in the space of QFD/Particles and General Relativity (or Astrophysics and Cosmology too).